# What happens when char * is assigned to a python object?

Tags: python, cython

I have following code.

```
cdef char * buf
buf = <LPSTR>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size)
# Some work on buff.
py_byte_string = buf
PyMem_Free(buf)
return py_byte_string
```

It looks like buf is been freed and py_byte_string is sent back to caller. Is this code is ok? I don't have any functional issues. But not comfortable with returning a freed pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be suspicious... Use `cython -a <filename>` to look at the code it generates (or skip the "-a" and look at the raw c file).

I won't paste it all here, because there's quite a bit of it, but somewhere near the top of the function is:

```
char *__pyx_v_buf;
char *__pyx_v_py_byte_string;
```

(i.e. py_byte_string is assumed to be a char pointer)

`py_byte_string = buf` is translated to

```
__pyx_v_py_byte_string = __pyx_v_buf;
```

And then the conversion takes place at the return statement (`return py_byte_string`):

```
__Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_r);
__pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBytes_FromString(__pyx_v_py_byte_string); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 78; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
__pyx_r = __pyx_t_2;
__pyx_t_2 = 0;
goto __pyx_L0;
```

Since this is after you've freed the memory it's pure good fortune that it works, and you could probably break it by allocating and using some more memory in between the free and the return.

All you need to do to force it to work safely is add

```
cdef object py_byte_string # tell Cython this should be a plain Python object
```

then the conversion takes place at the assignment line, where it should do.

For reference `__Pyx_PyBytes_FromString` looks to be a macro for `PyBytes_FromString`, which is specified as copying the string it's passed, so all should be safe there.

Comment: "cdef object py_byte_string" is a ideal solution. But i reverted to C way of solving.  Returning "cdef char *" from the function and freeing it after the use.